# In a passive tense when should I add 'being' in a combined statement?

Tags: grammar

Should I write like:

> I don't like his manner, it is like I owed him a billion and am required to pay him back.

or:

> I don't like his manner, it is like I owed him a billion and required to pay him back.

because I should "be required", I think the first one is more logical, but it sounds wired.

The second one sounds more nature but is it grammatically correct?

Comment: Or `it is like I owed him a billion and  I am required to pay him back.`  ? It is definitely correct, but is it kind of too formal?

Comment: You shouldn't write either of those. They’re both wrong in many ways. Please see [ell.se].

Comment: Just - "I don't like his manner, he acts like I owe him a billion" - (notice owe in the present tense). Also the "...required to pay him back." is superfluous - that is exactly what is meant by "owe" - a requirement or obligation to pay.

Comment: @Fraser - Is "owe" really correct? One has to use the subjunctive, no?

Comment: If you use the subjunctive *owed*, then the next verb should match its mood: *were required*. — But the subjunctive is now too formal to go with *like*, which I'd then change to *as if*.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, neither are good to be honest. I think this would work better:

> I don't like his manner, it's like I owe him a billion and I'm required to pay him back.

Comment: This is neither passive nor a good construction.